# How can I use keyup and down true false

Tags: javascript, css, keyup, onkeydown

I have the following code to allow user to enter single digit code in an input box, if user presses delete key, then, I would like to recheck some condition and allow user type again. How do I do it?:

```
$('.code').bind('keyup', function(event) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log("value.." + value.length);
    if (value.length === 1) {
        $('.InputInsertCodeLast').bind('keydown', function(event) {
            var code = event.keyCode || event.which;
            console.log('You pressed a "key" key in textbox' + event.keyCode);
            if ((code === 8 || code === 46) || (value.length === 0)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                //code to not allow any changes to be made to input field
                return false;
            }
        });
    } else if (value.length === 0) {
        console.log("value.length,,0");
        $('.InputInsertCodeLast').bind('keydown', function(event) {
            console.log("value.length,22,0");
            return true;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Why `android` tag?

Comment: I need itr to work on android devices

Answer (score 0):

https://plnkr.co/edit/SpjcKkTA4UaJ0GzzEuYf?p=info

```
    window.onload = function() {
  window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if(event.key === 'Backspace'){
      console.log('backspace');
    }
  });
}
```

of course this is just a suggest to give an idea how things work, you can workout a more efficent solution based on this :)